# Redundant chunk in mongo shard

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am testing mongodb sharding on my local machine. Everything seems to run fine, except that my first chunk is redundant. 
I initially had a mongod instance running, which had 100,000 entries like this,

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d788d26d664906cb359203"), "ind" : 123, "123" : 123, "someThing" : 5656 }` .

I had indexed this instance on `'ind'`. So, basically there were hundred thousand entries, `ind` is in the range from 0 to 100000.

After the whole deployment of sharding.

I run `sh.status()` on my mongos instance i got this.

`--- Sharding Status-- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "version" : 4,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 4,
    "currentVersion" : 5,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("53d74302e7df70cc9b8394e3")
}
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "localhost:104" }
    {  "_id" : "shard0001",  "host" : "localhost:105" }
    {  "_id" : "shard0002",  "host" : "localhost:106" }
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
    {  "_id" : "test",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
        test.data
            shard key: { "ind" : 1 }
            chunks:
                shard0001   1
                shard0002   2
                shard0000   1
    { "ind" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "ind" : 0 } on : shard0001 Timestamp(2, 0) 
    { "ind" : 0 } -->> { "ind" : 25000 } on : shard0002 Timestamp(3, 2) 
    { "ind" : 25000 } -->> { "ind" : 50000 } on : shard0002 Timestamp(3, 3) 
    { "ind" : 50000 } -->> { "ind" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard0000 Timestamp(3, 1)`

This was my initial state. After adding some data :

`--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "version" : 4,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 4,
    "currentVersion" : 5,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("53d74302e7df70cc9b8394e3")
}
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "localhost:104" }
    {  "_id" : "shard0001",  "host" : "localhost:105" }
    {  "_id" : "shard0002",  "host" : "localhost:106" }
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
    {  "_id" : "test",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
        test.data
            shard key: { "ind" : 1 }
            chunks:
                shard0001   4
                shard0002   4
                shard0000   4
        { "ind" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "ind" : 0 } on : shard0001 Timestamp(2, 0) 
        { "ind" : 0 } -->> { "ind" : 25000 } on : shard0002 Timestamp(3, 2) 
        { "ind" : 25000 } -->> { "ind" : 50000 } on : shard0002 Timestamp(3, 3) 
        { "ind" : 50000 } -->> { "ind" : 87449 } on : shard0001 Timestamp(4, 0) 
        { "ind" : 87449 } -->> { "ind" : 149796 } on : shard0001 Timestamp(5, 0) 
        { "ind" : 149796 } -->> { "ind" : 224694 } on : shard0002 Timestamp(6, 0) 
        { "ind" : 224694 } -->> { "ind" : 299592 } on : shard0001 Timestamp(7, 0) 
        { "ind" : 299592 } -->> { "ind" : 374490 } on : shard0002 Timestamp(8, 0) 
        { "ind" : 374490 } -->> { "ind" : 524286 } on : shard0000 Timestamp(8, 1) 
        { "ind" : 524286 } -->> { "ind" : 674082 } on : shard0000 Timestamp(7, 2) 
        { "ind" : 674082 } -->> { "ind" : 992211 } on : shard0000 Timestamp(7, 3) { "ind" : 992211 } -->> { "ind" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shard0000 Timestamp(3,5)`

My shard key was also `ind`. 
But `"ind" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "ind" : 0 } on : shard0001 Timestamp(2, 0)`
is clearly not right `.

My first chunk will always be empty.

What should I do?

Comment: Could you clarify what the problem is? The first chunk won't always be empty. You could add a document with `ind < 0`. It might not be empty now, if you added any documents with `ind < 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have got an empty first chunk. 
**From MongoDB docs :** A chunk is empty if it has no documents associated with its shard key range.

**IMPORTANT**
Empty chunks can make the balancer assess the cluster as properly balanced when it is not.
Empty chunks can occur under various circumstances, including:

If a pre-split creates too many chunks, the distribution of data to chunks may be uneven.
If you delete many documents from a sharded collection, some chunks may no longer contain data.

The problem in your case is there are no consecutive chunks (empty + non empty) on the same shard which can be merged. So for now you will have to live with it.
Refer the below link: 
[Merge chunks in sharded cluster](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/merge-chunks-in-sharded-cluster/)